# How to set background to listview?

Tags: android, listview, background

I want set background to listview , this photos show purpose

**[photo one : this is the xml file , show background !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oULax.png)**
but **[photo two see!! when run don't show background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQsSb.png)**

this is the code in java file

```
public class a extends ListActivity {

String[] listItems = {"سه‌ره‌تای ئیمان ـ باوه‌ڕ ـ وتنی: (لا اله الا الله)یه‌","فه‌رمانم پێكراوه‌ بجه‌نگم له‌گه‌ڵ خه‌ڵكیدا هه‌تا ده‌ڵێن (لا اله الا الله)"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(a.this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));

}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

if (position == 0) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, a_a_activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
} else if (position == 1) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, a_a_activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simply. by `getListView()` you can do it.

like this code:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class a extends ListActivity {

String[] listItems = {
        "سه‌ره‌تای ئیمان ـ باوه‌ڕ ـ وتنی: (لا اله الا الله)یه‌",
        "فه‌رمانم پێكراوه‌ بجه‌نگم له‌گه‌ڵ خه‌ڵكیدا هه‌تا ده‌ڵێن (لا اله الا الله)" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(a.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));
    // Get Active listView
    getListView().setBackground(R.drawable.your_background);

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    if (position == 0) {
        // Intent intent = new Intent(this, a_a_activity.class);
        // startActivity(intent);
    } else if (position == 1) {
        // Intent intent = new Intent(this, a_a_activity.class);
        // startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

when you use `ListActivity` you can get your `ListView` by calling method:

```
ListView list = getListView(); // OR you can do
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);  //consider the android prefix..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the ListView within a `ListActivity` using `getListView()`

```
getListView().setBackgroundColor(0xFFDED2BE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using getListView() method.

```
public class a extends ListActivity {

String[] listItems = {"سه‌ره‌تای ئیمان ـ باوه‌ڕ ـ وتنی: (لا اله الا الله)یه‌","فه‌رمانم پێكراوه‌ بجه‌نگم له‌گه‌ڵ خه‌ڵكیدا هه‌تا ده‌ڵێن (لا اله الا الله)"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(a.this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));

//getListView.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.your_background_image));


}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

if (position == 0) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, a_a_activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
} else if (position == 1) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, a_a_activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(a.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));
    // Get Active listView
  getListView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_file_name);

}
```